# jQuery post with JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have this jQuery code which use $.post for Ajax:

```
$.post(ajax_url , { upload_id: upload_id },
function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(jQuery.type(response));
}, "json");
```

and the php code :

```
$data = Array(
'status' => '1',
'msg' => '',
'progress' => '0.24',
'time' =>'<span class="text-white">06:51</span> left (at 21KB/sec)',
'size' => '<span class="text-white">26KB</span> / 10.91MB (0.24%)');

echo json_encode($data);
die();
```

and it suppose the console print the json code and the type which is json.
the problem is not print any thing in the console, it means no response.

I put this in the Ajax code to see the error:

```
.fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(textStatus)});
```

and the alert was parsererror.

what is the problem ?

UPDATE

If I removed `"json"` from the ajax code, the response print the type `string`
and the code `{"status":1,"msg":"","progress":"0.15","time":"<span class=\"text-white\">11:11<\/span> left (at 10KB\/sec)","size":"<span class=\"text-white\">16KB<\/span> \/ 10.91MB (0.15%)"}`

I need it json

Comment: Check in browser console net what is response data

Comment: I told you in the question, nothing

Comment: is ajax_url valid?, what is upload_id? (works on my machine)

Comment: The reason why this parserror message occurs is that when you simply return a string or another value, it is not really Json, so the parser fails when parsing it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script

Comment: @Sam Segers check the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this in another page and show in console.

```
<?php
if($_POST){
header('Content-type:application/json');
$data = Array(
'status' => '1',
'msg' => '',
'progress' => '0.24',
'time' =>'<span class="text-white">06:51</span> left (at 21KB/sec)',
'size' => '<span class="text-white">26KB</span> / 10.91MB (0.24%)');
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
}

?>
<input type="button" onclick="senddata()" value="send" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
function senddata(){
    var upload_id=1
    $.post('test.php' , { upload_id: upload_id },
    function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    }, "json");
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Just copy this code in test.php and show in console what is response.

Comment: with `header('Content-type:application/json');` or without it it works
1

Comment: ya it with or without header('Content-type:application/json'); work.

Comment: Well , you solved it.
the real php code was passed text string with the json so it was not real json, you code made me look at the php return.

Comment: your json response is :-  {"status":1,"msg":"","progress":"0.15","time":"<span class=\"text-white\">11:11<\/span> left (at 10KB\/sec)","size":"<span class=\"text-white\">16KB<\/span> \/ 10.91MB (0.15%)"}

Comment: It should be :-[{"status":1,"msg":"","progress":"0.15","time":"<span class=\"text-white\">11:11<\/span> left (at 10KB\/sec)","size":"<span class=\"text-white\">16KB<\/span> \/ 10.91MB (0.15%)"}]

Comment: means you missed '[]' square brackets thats why return error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server sending data as Content-Type `"*/json"`? If not, modify the response headers accordingly. Sending `"application/json"` would be fine, for example. And the code would be: `header('Content-type:application/json');`

Another possible solution is by switching '\' to '/' in your json url.